# Progress bar doesn't show up while webview is loading

Tags: android, webview, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I have written sample webview code by looking at examples found from internet. I want to show progressbar till webview loads a page in my fragment.

My activity contains toolbar, frame that shows fragments and navigation drawer. When i select an entry from navigation drawer, new fragment is shown which contains progress bar and webview and the fragment simply tries to load the page below is the code for fragment

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_full_page, container, false);
    //int view_num = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webviewProgress);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
    //webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT );
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    String urlString = getArguments().getString("URLSTRING");
    final Boolean clickable = getArguments().getBoolean("CLICKABLE");

    Boolean networkAvailable = Utils.isNetworkAvailable(super.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    if(networkAvailable == true) {
        webView.loadUrl(urlString);
    } else {
        webView.loadUrl(Utils.DEFAULT_URL_PAGE);
    }

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (clickable) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    });

    webView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                WebView webView = (WebView) v;

                switch (keyCode) {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                            webView.goBack();
                            return true;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });


    return rootView;
}
```

Below is fragment_full_page.xml

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".FragmentFullPage" >

<ProgressBar
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
    android:id="@+id/webviewProgress"
    />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

web page is taking time to load (tried with wifi and 3g) but progress bar is not showing any time.

To test if progressbar actually shows in the middle of the fragment_full_page, I removed webview code and just kept progress bar then it is showing.

made something wrong with the code that is not showing progress bar while webview is loading which i am unable to figure out.

Comment: Try moving the progress bar xml part below the webview, so that it will render above it

Comment: excellent worked. thank you for saving my time